# Disable BottomSheetDialogFragment from showing

Tags: android, android-bottomsheetdialog

I am having two Bottom Sheet Dialog Fragment layouts which I have included in a `CoordinatorLayout`. The `CoordinatorLayout` has a `RecyclerView` whose items show one Bottom Sheet dialog fragment upon being clicked. The first bottom sheet dialog fragment is used to update the items of the recycler view. The second Bottom Sheet Dialog Fragment is used to perform a payment of the items. The issue am having is that when i show the second Bottom Sheet for payment and mistakenly click on the items the 1st bottom sheet comes below the second. Is there a way i can set the first bottom sheet dialog to be disabled or visibility set to gone like in buttons when the second bottom sheet is shown

Here is my XML

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.CartActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/cart_tool_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorWhiteShade">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/cart_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@color/colorWhiteDarker"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_sub_total"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/sub_total"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/sub_total"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/sub_total"
                            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:textSize="17sp"
                            />

                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/view"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_width="350dp"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:background="@color/colorBlack20"
                            android:layout_margin="2dp"
                            android:layout_below="@id/sub_total"/>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/view"
                            android:layout_margin="2dp"
                            android:padding="2dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/btn_post_payment"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="35dp"
                                android:drawableStart="@drawable/pay_icon"
                                android:text="@string/pay"
                                android:background="@drawable/ripple"
                                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                                android:textAllCaps="false"/>

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Always include layout below all the other layouts -->
    <include layout="@layout/layout_cart_bottom_sheet"/>

    <!-- Always include layout below all the other layouts -->
    <include layout="@layout/layout_post_payment"/>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Another implementation that i may like is if the 1st dialog can check if the second dialog is already showing and prevent it from showing again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the visibility as:

`<include layout="@layout/layout_cart_bottom_sheet" visibility="gone"/>`

or set an id to the layout as:

`<include android:id="@+id/cart_bottomsheet" layout="@layout/layout_cart_bottom_sheet">`

and toggle visibility using `findViewById` and `setVisibility`.

Comment: Do you have  a way of disabling the layout programatically, here is what i have tried and the app keeps on crushing:   View layout_cart_bottom_sheet = findViewById(R.id.layout_cart_bottom_sheet);
        layout_cart_bottom_sheet.setVisibility(View.GONE);